# Adding value from inputbox into combo box

Tags: javascript

Using javascript, (no jQuery libraries)

What i'd like to do is when I type a value into the inputbox and I hit my enter key (in the textbox only) i'd like to have the value of the inputbox be added into the drop down box.

Note that if there is an existing value in the already in the drop down box, the next value should just be added below the existing value.

How do I set this up?

Here is the html setup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<input type="text" id="theinput" style="width: 100px;">

<select id="thebox" style="width: 100px;"></select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function displayResult(event)
{
if(event.keyCode == 13)
{
var x=document.getElementById("thebox");
var option=document.createElement("option");
var txtv=document.getElementById("theinput");
option.text=txtv.value;
try
  {
  // for IE earlier than version 8
  x.add(option,x.options[null]);
  }
catch (e)
  {
  x.add(option,null);
  }
}
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="thebox">
</select>
</form>
<br>
<input type="text" id="theinput" onkeyup="displayResult(event)"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Link in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/49/

Answer (score 1):

**First** - lets add an event listener, that will be fired when user press a key

**Second** - Let's make a function passing the element you want to get the user input and set the value in the document

**Third** - let's create the dom element and add it to the *out element* you've created:

```
<script>
    //your input element
    var in = document.getElementById("theinput");
    //step 2
    function addItem(e) {
      //check if user press Enter
        if (e.keycode == 13) {            
            var out = document.getElementById("thebox");

            //step 3
            var optionElement = document.createElement("option"); //will create al <option> tag
            var text = document.createTextNode(in .value); //the value you inserted
            optionElement.appendChild(optionElement); // add the text to <option>
            out.appendChild(optionElement); // add the option to <select>
        }
    }
//Step 1 - add Eventlistener
  in.addEventListener("keydown", addItem, false);
</script>
```

Obs.: dont tested it. Make the necessary adjustments.